# Bundle install not working with gem 'sqlite' and 'pg'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I was about to deploy my app so i was updating the gem file to be.

```
group :development do
  gem ‘sqlite3’
end

group :production do
  gem ‘pg’
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

When i run the bundle install i get an error saying 'Undefined local variable or method `‘sqlite3’' for Gemfile' which is weird because previously sqlite was the only gem in the file.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use single `'` or double quotes `"` around gem names like you've done for `rails_12factor`.  Update your Gemfile as follows:

```
group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```